# Compass metadata tag in photos

Tags: c#, gps, photo, exif, xmp

We have a GPS enable camera that also stores the compass direction or bearing in the metadata in the photo.  The GPS X and Y and other GPS information is stored in the GPSInfo tag in the EXIF data, however compass direction is not there.

Does anyone know where I can find about where this tag is stored in the file?  I have looked up the XMP specs as well but couldn't find anything.

I'm writing my own photo mapping software, so I don't want existing apps that do this.

Comment: you've duplicated this question...

Comment: sorry, I must have hit enter by accident.  I'll keep this one because it is the newer one and has the better tags. Deleted the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all good I found the tag I was looking for:

```
Exif.GPSInfo.GPSImgDirection
```

I found a good site to show all the tags that EXIF has [here](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/EXIF.html)